# Does Apache Spark Partitioning (for multiple RDDs/DFs) maintain data-locality on the worker nodes?

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, partitioning

Let's say I have multiple DataFrames partitioned by same column.

When I now try to do operations (like joins, creating objects of them and using in a logic, etc.) is it ensured that all the data concerned to a particular worker node is already present there (while partitioning)?

Otherwise it will cause shuffle which is expensive.
Ex.

```
If DFs are as follows: 

d1, d2 => data in columns 
p1, p2 => Partition

DF1 => (d1, d2, d3, p1)
       (d4, d5, d6, p2)

DF2 => (d7, d8, d9,   p1)
      (d10, d11, d12, p2)
```

Then will the partitioning be as follows, i.e. Worker nodes having the required data locally?

```
Workernode 1: (d1, d2, d3, p1) 
              (d7, d8, d9, p1)

Workernode 2: (d4, d5, d6, p2) 
              (d10, d11, d12, p2)
```

Comment: How would spark know to localize the data before any operation occurs? The localization will only happen after a relation is established between `DF1` and `DF2` (join etc.). A shuffle will happen and then the data belonging to the same partition will be moved to the same node.

Comment: If we take care of putting all the DFs required for the operation to the same concerned worker node, then shuffling would not take place right?

Comment: And I'm assuming putting all the required DFs on the same worker nodes will be taken care by partitioning them accordingly. Please let me know if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Defining a partition on a dataframe will not move or localize your data automatically. As I mentioned earlier, a relation needs to be established between the dataframes so Spark knows what to localize. Also, as far as I know, you can't forcefully load your dataframe to a specific worker node. It's all premature optimization that you don't really need.